# count div elements with the same id JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a more than one **DIV** with the same ID. I want to keep track of the number of **DIV's** by using **JQUERY**. This one does not seem to work.

```
var divid = "123456";
var count_id_len = $("#parentdiv").find("#"+divid).length;
console.log(count_id_len);
```

The result is always **1** even though there is more than one of them.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: ID of an element must be unique, use `class`/other attributes to group similar elements

Comment: Oh, that's why, thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Give class name for div and paste the below code..
It will give the count.

```
var conveniancecount = $("div[class*='conveniancecount']").length;
```

Comment: that's a nice idea. i'll try it. i'll get back to you.

Comment: If u got the solution mark as answer else comment here i will clear your doubts..

Comment: What about `$('.yourclassName')` ?

Comment: @Sasidharan Because in your selector all the divs will get selected having class names as `myconveniancecount,conveniancecounted,`  etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

Having same id multiple times is not recommended by W3C. See what they say about it.

> The id attribute specifies a **unique id** for an HTML element (**the id attribute value must be unique within the HTML document**).
>   The id attribute can be used to point to a style in a style sheet.
>   The id attribute can also be used by a JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to make changes to the HTML element with the specific id.

Suggestion:

Use class name for all the divs you want to group and use this selector:

```
$('.myClassName')
```

See these references for more:

[1. Why do Ids need to be unique](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can be useful for you:

I've been making inner ajax calls wich may be the container starts wrapping inside one time and another in some cases. I resolve it with this:

```
jQuery("div[id='yourWrapper_1']").length
```

Try unwrapping it, because you shouldn't have repeated ID's on your DOM

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Hope it helps you

Regards!

Comment: I found it useful to be able to count the number of DOM elements with the duplicate ID as part of investigating a bug which led to duplicate DOM elements being added. Yes, it's invalid HTML, but it's still useful to be able to count them for bug investigations.