# Is there a way to count how many database results the PHP sends back to jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, while-loop

In my project, I use PHP to query the database(in my case, SELECT) and use while loop to fetch each row, and use it to echo back to ajax.

Like in my PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks A WHERE A.open = '1'";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo $row["orderDetails"];
}
```

In my HTML:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "getDetails.php",
            success: function(backData){
                $("#details").html(backData);
            }
     });
<script>
```

Let's say I query the database for the open tasks in my task table where task.open=1, then inside of each open task, I echo back to my ajax about these tasks details, and my ajax will change the html of the div about the task details.

So basically, the number of the open tasks, aka the number of the while loops, is the number of the echos. What is the best way to grab this number so I can show in the html how many tasks are listed here?

PS: I tried to catch this number by adding a while loop counter inside of the while loop, and add this number to an attribute of the div and echo back to ajax, however, I don't know why this echo will not take place in my end.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I found a way of thought. I will count how many that divs are in my html.

Comment: I suddenly came up with another question. Is the html() is jquery actually will add the content to the selected element or replace it entirely?

Comment: As explained in [the `.html()` method's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/), it replaces the existing content.

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn, that's what I thought, but why I am asking this question is because when I echo back the data in a while loop to the ajax and in my jQuery I select the div with the unique id to use html() to replace the content, the div will actually add up to the number of the echos at the front end. If it replaces the content, why doesn't it only show the last echo content instead of showing all the echos??

Comment: The browser doesn't receive the echoes individually, it receives a single response from the server that includes the text of all of the echoes all concatenated together. The browser has no way of knowing (and doesn't care) whether the PHP used a single `echo` statement, or a loop, or neither.

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh! That's how it works?! So echo in PHP actually works like it adds up all echos in that php and then sends them back all together at once. Thank you for the explanation! Solves my long time mystery haha :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is send back a proper JSON response, then you can just use the `length` property to check how many items there are. You don't need a loop to do this, just use PDO's [`fetchAll` method](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). Since you are only selecting a single column, you can get it as an array of strings.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT orderDetails FROM tasks WHERE open=1";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($array);
```

Now you have an array of strings, you can do what you want with it, including [getting its length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "getDetails.php",
        success: function(backData) {
            // now you can work with backData as an object
            var count = backData.length;
            $("#details").append("<div>You have " + count + " results.</div>");
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                $("#details").append("<div>" + backData[i] + "</div>"
            }
        }
    });
});
<script>
```

Also note you were missing a closing `})` pair in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Oh well! That's a very smart way to solve my problem! I haven't dived into JSON that much yet but really I have to learn it very soon! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a div with a class attribute to the echo to contain this order details and then back to my html I used jQuery to count the div with that specific class and get the number. I get the hint from here: [count div elements with the same id JQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898896/count-div-elements-with-the-same-id-jquery)
But you are very welcome to post a better solution for this :D